# confusion between props and state in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed a tutorial and came out with this https://jsbin.com/foxoxejilu/1/edit?js,output using react.js.

I'm confused with the props and state. In the `save` method of `Note component` , what does this line do

```
this.props.onChange(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.id)
```

And I don't see onChange and onRemove function elsewhere in the code, is that a pre-build function of react? how does react know the DOM got changed or removed?

Comment: Where a note is instantiated (`<Note../>`) `onChange` is passed as a property.

Comment: @Koen. What does it means? how about onRemove? is that a build in feature or just a normal props?

Comment: Same, but it sounds like you don't even know the basics of React and JSX, so I suggest you start reading the documentation. E.g. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: @Koen. I do. Just that in this example I'm confused because there are chaining between components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could summarise what is happening like this:

A Parent (`Board`) packs her Child (`Note`) a bag (`props`) and puts a mobile phone (`onChange`) and says: if you want to tell me something just text me the message. Then after some time the Child thinks "let's text my parent" so the Child takes the phone out of his properties and texts the Parent: `this.props.onChange("Thank you for sandwiches")`. The Parent, then receives the message and saves it into her notebook (`state`): `this.setState({notes})`

This is where the child receives the properties (props):

```
<Note key={note.id}
      id={note.id}
      onChange={this.update}
      onRemove={this.remove}>
      {note.note}
 </Note>
```

When the above finds its way to the `render()` method of the `Board` component (via `{this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}`, it's like `Board` saying,

- "Hey let's render the `Note` component and lets give it some properties (props)".
- "Let's name one of this props `onChange` and when it is invoked by the `Note` later, let's execute my own method called `update`"
- "Instaed of calling this prop `onChange` we could call it whatever we want, for example 
   `<Note ... fromParentWithLove={this.update}> ... </Note>`, but let's call it `onChange` so that it is easier to follow our intentions."

Then, we can move to the child component - `Note`. `Note` is saying to itself:

- "Wow, if someone clicks on Save button let's run my own `save` method:" `<button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>`
- "Then, inside my `save` method let's invoke the `onChange` function given to me by my parent `Board` via props": `this.props.onChange(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.id)`"

For reference, below is the code copied from the JSBin:

```
var Note = React.createClass({
        getInitialState(){
            return {editing: false}
        },
        edit() {
            this.setState({editing: true})
        },
        save() {
            this.props.onChange(this.refs.newText.value, this.props.id)
            this.setState({editing: false})
        },
        remove() {
            this.props.onRemove(this.props.id)
        },
        renderForm() {
            return(
                <div className="note">
                    <textarea ref="newText"></textarea>
                    <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
                </div>
            )
        },
        renderDisplay() {
            return(
                <div className="note">
                    <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                    <span>
                        <button onClick={this.edit}>Edit</button>
                        <button onClick={this.remove}>X</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        },
        render() {
            return (this.state.editing) ? this.renderForm() : this.renderDisplay()
        }
    })

 var Board = React.createClass({
        propTypes: {
            count: function(props, propName) {
                if(typeof props[propName] !== 'number'){
                    return new Error('the count must be a number')
                }
            }
        },
        getInitialState() {
            return {
                notes: [
                {id:1, note:'Call boook'},
                {id:2, note:'Buy Something'},
                {id:3, note:'Wash Clothes'},
                {id:4, note:'Go Jogging'}
                ]
            }
        },
        update(newText, id){
            var notes = this.state.notes.map(
                note => (note.id !== id) ?
                    note:
                    {
                        ...note,
                        note:newText
                    }
            )
            this.setState({notes})
        },
        remove(id){
            var notes = this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== id)
            this.setState({notes})
        },
        eachNote(note) {
            return (<Note key={note.id}
                          id={note.id}
                          onChange={this.update}
                          onRemove={this.remove}>
                      {note.note}
                    </Note>)
        },
        render() {
            return (<div className='board'>
                       {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
                    </div>)
        }
    })

ReactDOM.render(<Board count={10}> </Board>, 
        document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

Comment: I got it. But do u think this is too complicated to do simple thing? if I will do it I wonder create a parent for note because it can be a plain container.

Comment: The nice thing about it, is that it reflects what we do in real life: A parent (`Board`) pack her child (`Note`) a bag (`props`) and puts a mobile phone ( `onChange`) and says: if you want to tell me something just text me the message. Then after some time the child thinks "let's text my parent": (`this.props.onChange("thank you for sandwiches") `)